# EXC_BAD_ACCESS assigning to variable right after function call

Tags: c, macos, exc-bad-access, lldb

I'm writing a very simple C program for a basic course, and I have been getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on line 14. I can't see what the problem is.
The program asks the user for a number, and then displays the ASCII character associated with it.

This only happens, AFAIK, when debugging my program with `lldb`. It works perfectly fine when running from the command line, or on [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler).
Also, if I comment out line 13, and assign `true` or `false` to `loop_ctrl`, instead of the return value of `UserWantsToExit`, everything works as expected.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    void GetAndDisplayInput(void);
    bool UserWantsToExit(void);

    int main()
    {
        bool loop_ctrl = true;

        while (loop_ctrl)
        {
            GetAndDisplayInput();
            loop_ctrl = !UserWantsToExit(); /* EXC_BAD_ACCESS */
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void GetAndDisplayInput()
    {
        char input_char = '0';

        printf("\nInput a number: ");
        scanf("%i", &input_char);
        getc(stdin); /* Gets rid of '\n' */

        printf("\n\nIt's character '%c'!\n\n", input_char);
    }

    bool UserWantsToExit()
    {
        char choice = '0';
        bool value = false;

        printf("\nDo you want to exit? (Y/N): ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        getc(stdin); /* Gets rid of '\n' */
        value = (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: You should correct your first scanf, as %i is for signed integer and you provide a char, which is wrong. Apart that, your code seem to be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format descriptor `%i` used in the call to `scanf()` in function `GetAdnDisplayInput()` requires a corresponding argument of type pointer to `int`. You are passing a pointer to `char`. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Note that your C compiler should have warned you about the mismatch between the format descriptor and the corresponding argument; you should make a habit of compiling with all possible warnings turned on.

Comment: Yes, my compiler did warn me about that. I just didn't think it would solve the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've modified my code accordingly and now I can debug it. Thanks!